# How to delete files permanently (not to recycle bin) with TortoiseProc

Tags: svn, automation, tortoisesvn

I executed the command line:

```
TortoiseProc.exe /command:cleanup /revert /delunversioned /delignored /refreshshell /path:"%~1" /noui /closeonend:1
```

and all files were deleted to the recycle bin.

I found this message :

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/tortoisesvn/Tb-LUnmosj0/2ez-ocdEbdgJ

but cannot find this option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure the behavior in the settings dialog:

> Settings->Dialogs 1->Use recycle bin when reverting

If you remove the checkmark, then TortoiseSVN will not use the recycle bin anymore but simply delete the files.

Comment: No, sorry. That's a global setting which is not configurable on the command line.